# UbuntuでSublime Text3の日本語入力

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext

初めての質問失礼します。

普段WindowsでSublime Text3を使用しており、Ubuntu環境でも使いたかったので、https://qiita.com/kanpou0108/items/bc739c1215fc222f17c8を参考に日本語入力をできるようにするパッケージSublimeMozcInputの追加を試みたのですがうまく行きません。

コンソールでは

Package Control: Error downloading repository. HTTP exception InvalidCertificateException (Host api.github.com returned an invalid certificate ([SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:548))) downloading https://api.github.com/repos/yasuyuky/SublimeMozcInput.

と出ており、[Githubのフォーラム](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/1334)では同じような問題に遭遇した人がいるようです。しかし自分の英語力で試せる範囲のものはダメでした。同じ問題にあった方がいましたらご教授願います。

Answer (score 1):

今現在ではPackage ContolからSublimeMozcInputをインストールすることはできないようなので、yudachiさんの症状は確認できないのですが、GitHubリポジトリから直接プラグインをクローンすることでSublimeMozcInputが使えるようになりました。

これがSublimeMozcInputのGitHubリポジトリです。ここから[Preferences] > [Browse Packages...]で出てきたフォルダにクローンしてください。
https://github.com/yasuyuky/SublimeMozcInput

あとは[このSublimeMozcInputの公式ページ](http://yasuyuky.github.io/SublimeMozcInput/)にあるとおりです。